# Bound mismatch error using Generics

Tags: java, generics, collections

When I tried to compile my previous java 1.4 code in 1.5 I got this generics Bound mismatch problem. The code is given below

```
try {
    ArrayList simplePrincipals = new ArrayList(
            ((java.util.Collection) (subject.getPrincipals(Class
                    .forName("com.efunds.security.jaas.SimplePrincipal")))));
    if (simplePrincipals.size() > 0) {
        ((SimplePrincipal) simplePrincipals.get(0))
                .setPermissions(webPerm);
    }
}
```

**the error is :**

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `getPrincipals(Class<T>)` of type Subject is not applicable for the arguments `(Class<capture#1-
>        of ?>)`. The inferred type `capture#1-of ?` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Principal>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at [the Javadocs,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html#getPrincipals%28java.lang.Class%29) you'll see that `getPrincipals()` is now defined to take a `Class<T extends Principal>` -- i.e., a `Class` object representing a subclass of `Principal`. Your code has to take this into account, for example, by using the `asSubclass()` method:

```
String className = "com.efunds.security.jaas.SimplePrincipal";
Class<? extends Principal> clazz =
    Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Principal.class); 
ArrayList<Principal> simplePrincipals =
    new ArrayList<Principal>(subject.getPrincipals(clazz));
```

Note that your cast to `Collection` as well as most of the parentheses are unnecessary.